# Downloaded pdf showing as plain text in mpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf, codeigniter-4

Please help me to solve this issue.

Pdf downloaded successfully but showing as plain text in chrome android device and even if we open pdf without download it is showing as plain text.

FYR: I am using PHP version 7.2 and codeignitor version 4.

Here is my code.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->showImageErrors = false;
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('pdf_application_view', $data));
$filename = "Application No.";
$mpdf->Output($filename, 'D');
```

I have also tried header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
But not fixied. Kindly help to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75316.html check out this, maybe helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, solved it by first saving the file to the server, then downloading it. I have no idea why it had to be that way, but here's some code:

```
    $mpdf->Output('./tmp/' . $file_name, 'F');
    $mpdf->Output($file_name, 'D');
```